# When is the diode conducting in this circuit?

Tags: diodes

[image]

Can someone tell me when is the diode conducting and when it isn't? I did calculate the voltage between its electrodes, so I disconnected the diode, then for some unknown reason I turned the current generator into a tension generator with voltage \$R_2 I_G\$ (someone explain this please), and calculated the voltage using Millman’s theorem, which is \$V = \frac{\frac{E}{R_1} - I_G}{\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2}}\$, then assuming the diode has a base voltage \$V_d\$ from my textbook, the diode is conducting if \$V > V_d\$ and vice versa, but in this case, when the diode is conducting, we replace the diode with a tension generator which voltage is exactly \$V_d\$.

[image]

Comment: In English, the word is "voltage", not "tension"; some people might not be familiar with the term "tension" used in this way. We also usually refer to them as voltage sources and current sources, not generators, but it's easy enough to know what you mean there.

Comment: @Hearth ah but do you see my confusion though?

Comment: Unfortunately, no; I've read your question a few times and I'm not really sure what you're asking. Could you try to clarify what the actual question is?

Comment: I think im more confused on why when the diode is conducting we swapped it with a generator of voltage with voltage = V_d, and why we have that expression of the current.

Answer (score 1):

> for some unknown reasons i turned the current generator into a tension generator

This is called *source conversion* also called *source transformation*. A current source in parallel with a resistor can be turned into a voltage source in series with a resistor of the same value and vice versa.

Your textbook should have the information to support this.

Comment: "Source transformation" is another common word for it.

Answer (score 0):

Swapping a diode for a voltage source is only valid when the diode is forward-biased. If you've already verified that the diode is not forward-biased, which you did before applying the source transformation, you can't swap it for a voltage source.

Comment: How do i know that a diode is forward-biased?, also if its a perfect diode no internal resistance then its voltage is constant ?

Comment: @HellBoy When the anode is at a higher potential than the cathode. Alternatively, when current is flowing through the diode in the forward direction. (assuming negligible reverse recovery time)

Comment: @HellBoy   Do the calculations twice, once for each diode state, and only one will be consistent. Once you've done that a few times, you'll start to gain some intuition about which it's likely to be.

Comment: @Hearth but why exactly replacing the diode with $V_d$ and not V, like is there a maximum limit of voltage that the diode can hold and the other rest like $V-V_d$ is dispersed?

Comment: @HellBoy That's part of the approximation. Diodes have very close to a constant forward voltage regardless of how much current flows through them.

Comment: @HellBoy Your average diode will release the magic smoke in short order if you connect it across a voltage source even just slightly greater than its forward voltage. This is why, for instance, LEDs always need to be driven with a constant current source or else given a ballast resistor (which acts like a poor, but good enough, current source).